# Joomla menu and K2 categories. How do I

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I am using Joomla 2.5 as CMS for my website, and I am using K2 for categories and articles/items. I was wondering if i have list of 50 - K2 categories. 
It has 5 main categories and 10 sub categories for each.

How can I either manually or automatically  make categories listed in main menu and when user clicks for example:

Home >> Contact >> Products >> About >> Call

If user selects Contact, how can I make it so it loads page which displays all articles/items in category called "Contact" but if User selects specific sub item from Contact for example:

Contact
^^Phone
^^Email
^^Skype
^^Post

if user selects Email it would show only articles/items from category Contact>>Email.

Help?

Comment: Have you read K2 documentation or watched the videos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Menu item called Categories for example, or 10 menu items each one for your top categories.

Then you can start adding submenu items, for example in the top menu level called Contact add the Email sub-categorie. So when users visit your website can navigate through the menu to all categories you got.

An other way to do it faster is to use this plugin: http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/addtomenu but I think it only works for items and not for categories (but you can ask the developer).

IMPORTANT: You can have top-categories configured to show only the items of this one or also with sub-categories, and can create a K2 menu item which can display in one link lot of categories you can choose in the parameters using CTRL+CLICK (even from other top categories).